# How to provide correctly parameters in Alamofire

Tags: swift, request, alamofire

I try to use trackingmore API and I using alamofire to do request. But I have a problem with providing a tracking number in the request. That is my response `SUCCESS: {`

```
data =     (
);
meta =     {
    code = 4013;
    message = "Tracking_number is required.";
    type = "Bad Request";
};
```

and that is my code

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Trackingmore-Api-Key": "secretKey",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]

    let parameters = [
        "tracking_number": "1Z21F31F0386694086",
        "carrier_code": "ups",
    ]
    Alamofire.request("https://api.trackingmore.com/v2/trackings/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters ,headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
    }
```

I did something wrong with providing parameters? And how I can fix this?

Comment: As trackingmore dev docs referring, Please try *POST* `/trackings/post` and then *GET* `/trackings/get`.

Comment: https://www.trackingmore.com/help_article-29-27-en.html

Comment: What error message you are getting?

Comment: The error message is in response, and I using post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :) I had to add encoding to JSON
`Alamofire.request("https://api.trackingmore.com/v2/trackings/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
        }`